# Which is the notation for grouping elements from two sets two by two?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We can unite two sets $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{c\}$, by saying $C = A \cup B = \{a,b,c\}$. And we can perform a cartesian product like this:
$C = A \times B = \{\langle a,c \rangle, \langle b,c\rangle\}$

How can I represent the following set operation? Which symbol could be used in the place of '?'?
$$C = A ~?~ B = \{\{a,c\}, \{b,c\}\}$$

It is like the cartesian product, but resulting in a set of sets of size 2, instead of a set of pairs (tuples).

Comment: Because $\langle a,c\rangle = \{\{a\},\{a,c\}\}$ or something similar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair), then if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ there isn't much difference. Maybe check the books in the notes here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_pair) to see if they use a particular notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard notation for this. Probably the best thing to use is set-builder notation:
$$
C = \{ \{x, y\} : x \in A, y \in B \}.
$$
This will also allow for singletons. For example, if you would take $A = \{a,b,c\}$ and $B = \{c\}$, then you would get $\{c\} \in C$ (since $c$ is in both $A$ and $B$). If you do not want that, you can use
$$
C = \{ \{x, y\} : x \in A, y \in B, x \neq y \}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Don't know that there is one.

But if you want to formally defined such a set you can invent any notation you like and define:

$A?B = \{\{a,b\}|a\in A; b\in B\}$

Actually more to the point is the a symbol or function that we "unorder" an ordered tuple?  Something akin to $<a_1, ....., a_k>_u = \{a_1, ...., a_k\}$.

We can define such a function as $u: A\times B \to   \mathscr P(A\cup B)$ via $u(<a,b>) = \{a,b\}$ and then then set you want can be defined as $u(A\times B)$.

I don't know if there is a convention for the concept but.... you can certainly define what you need.

But thing is the only difference between $\{a,b\}$ and $<a,b>$ is a specified order. So many would simply call this an "unordered pair".

Comment: The set $\{a, c\}$ will not live in $A \cup B$, but rather in $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ (the powerset).

Comment: Good grief!   I knew that thought about that but then.... oh, bogger.... rookie mistake.